# Default height of status bar is not showing properly after upgrade library to android 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am working on an app, need to apply bottomsheet dialog, so I updated my **android.supppcom.android.support:design:23.1.1** to **com.android.support:design:23.2.1**. Everything is working fine, but here is the problem.

1. Status bar's default height is wider than normal(say if default is 10dp now height is 30dp).
2. It's preview is ok in Android studio's preview.

I don't know how it's working, so can anyone help me on this.Please find the gradle information.
Thanks

```
   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.inkapplications.viewpageindicator:library:2.4.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
// compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.codesnippets4all:quick-json:1.0.4'
   //    compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
  //    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
  //    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
   //    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
   //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   //    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

    }
```

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarAppHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
     <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_home"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lable"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_tournament"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_group_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lable"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_team"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_group_work_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lable"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_notification"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lable"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Above added is XML code of the activity view which launches when application starts. This activity has a framelayout in centre. That framelayout display a fragment say fragmentA. Here is the XML view code of this fragment.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#F8F8FF">


   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/appHomeRecycleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/xyz1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Status bar or ActionBar/Toolbar?

Comment: Status bar, Jared, where we find the wifi or mobile tower signals.

Comment: Support libraries do not change the height of the status bar

Comment: Thanks. But the same code was working fine before upgrade of library. Could you please tell me the approach to get the root cause.

Comment: Please, show us screenshot of both versions. While at it, please add your activity layout in the question. (Btw status bar is 25dp prior to Android 6 and 24dp since Android 6.)

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot and activity layout. Highlighted area is the unwanted width, before this upgarde it was not like this. To come to know the root cause I commented the appbarlayout code along with toolbar layout, then I came to know this is the status bar, its height is differ from default height. Please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I worked on it for more than 10 hours and finally found the solution. Here is the solution:

You can see a parameter inside the fragmentA layout XML file:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Change this paramter to false as:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Frankly telling, I don't why this is not working with new library 23.2.1, but it works fine in 23.1.1 version.

Hope this will help others.

Thanks

Prabhakar

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should **not** assume a fixed height of the status bar (especially when targeting older devices by various manufacturers). I used to do that and regretted it :p  AFAIK a ScrimInsetsFrameLayout (or similar) is the way to go here, see https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java